# Buildozer stopped working all of a sudden despite always uploading the same files to Colab

Tags: python, android, buildozer

> Check application requirements 
> Compile platform 
> Run '/usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=demo3 --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy,pillow,kivymd,asyncio,bleak --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21 --ignore-setup-py --debug' 
> Cwd /content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android

[INFO]:    Will compile for the following archs: armeabi-v7a 
[INFO]:    Found Android API target in $ANDROIDAPI: 27 
[INFO]:    Available Android APIs are (27) 
[INFO]:    Requested API target 27 is available, continuing.
[INFO]:    Found NDK dir in $ANDROIDNDK: /root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c 
[INFO]:    Found NDK version 19c 
[INFO]:    Getting NDK API version (i.e. minimum supported API) from user argument

Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"**main**", mod_spec) 
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals) 
File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1294, in 
main() 
File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main
ToolchainCL() 
File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 728, in **init**
getattr(self, command)(args) 
File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 144, in wrapper_func
user_ndk_api=self.ndk_api) 
File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 423, in prepare_build_environment
self.ccache = sh.which("ccache") 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sh-1.14.3-py3.7.egg/sh.py", line 1524, in **call**
return RunningCommand(cmd, call_args, stdin, stdout, stderr) 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sh-1.14.3-py3.7.egg/sh.py", line 788, in **init**
self.wait() 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sh-1.14.3-py3.7.egg/sh.py", line 845, in wait
self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code) 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sh-1.14.3-py3.7.egg/sh.py", line 869, in handle_command_exit_code 
raise exc 
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1:

RAN: /usr/bin/which ccache

STDOUT:

STDERR:

> Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=demo3 --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy,pillow,kivymd,asyncio,bleak --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21 --ignore-setup-py --debug

ENVIRONMENT: 
CUDNN_VERSION = '8.0.5.39' 
PYDEVD_USE_FRAME_EVAL = 'NO' 
LD_LIBRARY_PATH = '/usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64' 
CLOUDSDK_PYTHON = 'python3' 
LANG = 'en_US.UTF-8' 
ENABLE_DIRECTORYPREFETCHER = '1' 
HOSTNAME = 'ca63256296ed' 
OLDPWD = '/' 
CLOUDSDK_CONFIG = '/content/.config' 
USE_AUTH_EPHEM = '1' 
NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES = 'all' 
DATALAB_SETTINGS_OVERRIDES = '{"kernelManagerProxyPort":6000,"kernelManagerProxyHost":"172.28.0.3","jupyterArgs":["--ip=172.28.0.2"],"debugAdapterMultiplexerPath":"/usr/local/bin/dap_multiplexer","enableLsp":true}' 
ENV = '/root/.bashrc' 
PAGER = 'cat' 
NCCL_VERSION = '2.7.8' 
TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH = 'true' 
JPY_PARENT_PID = '41' 
NO_GCE_CHECK = 'False' 
PWD = '/content' 
HOME = '/root' 
LAST_FORCED_REBUILD = '20220712' 
CLICOLOR = '1' 
DEBIAN_FRONTEND = 'noninteractive' 
LIBRARY_PATH = '/usr/local/cuda/lib64/stubs' 
GCE_METADATA_TIMEOUT = '3' 
GLIBCPP_FORCE_NEW = '1' 
TBE_CREDS_ADDR = '172.28.0.1:8008' 
TERM = 'xterm-color' 
SHELL = '/bin/bash' 
GCS_READ_CACHE_BLOCK_SIZE_MB = '16' 
PYTHONWARNINGS = 'ignore:::pip._internal.cli.base_command' 
MPLBACKEND = 'module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline' 
CUDA_VERSION = '11.1.1' 
NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES = 'compute,utility' 
SHLVL = '1' 
PYTHONPATH = '/env/python' 
NVIDIA_REQUIRE_CUDA = ('cuda>=11.1 brand=tesla,driver>=418,driver<419 '
'brand=tesla,driver>=440,driver<441 brand=tesla,driver>=450,driver<451') 
TBE_EPHEM_CREDS_ADDR = '172.28.0.1:8009' 
COLAB_GPU = '0' 
GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW = '1' 
PATH = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/opt/bin:/usr/local/nvidia/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/tools/node/bin:/tools/google-cloud-sdk/bin' 
LD_PRELOAD = '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtcmalloc.so.4' 
GIT_PAGER = 'cat' 
_ = '/usr/local/bin/buildozer' 
PACKAGES_PATH = '/root/.buildozer/android/packages' 
ANDROIDSDK = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk' 
ANDROIDNDK = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c' 
ANDROIDAPI = '27' 
ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'

> Buildozer failed to execute the last command
> The error might be hidden in the log above this error
> Please read the full log, and search for it before
> raising an issue with buildozer itself.
> In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with the python-for-android build.py file which they currently fixing(something related to sh, and shoudl be fixed soon)
meanwhile as a workaround it is suggested to uncomment p4a.branch = master in the buildozer spec file and change the "master" to "develop"